Why does this start an infinite cycle?
I'm coding in C and it seems like the program ignores the scanf command and starts doing an infinite cycle if I insert anything other than a number. Does anyone know how to fix it or even what is going on?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NBITS 8

void inserimento() {
    int N, ret;

    do {
        printf("Immetti un numero maggiore di 1\n");
        ret = scanf("%d", &N);
    } while (ret == 0 || N <= 1);
}

int main() {
    int N;
    inserimento();
}

I've tried switching the order of the or statement and using the solution from the code my professor gave us but I'm pretty new to this so I don't know if I messed up in copying it.

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems? and How to debug small programs

This is because the characters remain in the keyboard buffer. You must therefore empty the keyboard buffer.

@CGi03 Not "keyboard buffer". It is a dangerous misconception. The characters remain in the stream and should be removed from the stream by reading them.

Never use scanf to interact with the user. Read all interactive input with fgets, then parse the resulting line. See here.

Repeat 1000 times: Never use scanf

This is because the characters remain in the stream. You must therefore empty the stream.
#include <stdio.h>

void fflush_stdin(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
}

void inserimento()
{
    int N, ret;
    do
    {
        printf("Immetti un numero maggiore di 1\n");
        ret = scanf("%d", &N);
        fflush_stdin();
    }
    while(ret==0 || N <= 1);
}

int main()
{
    inserimento();
}


When the first scanf("%d", &N) call returns EOF, ret==0 || N <= 1 attempts to evaluate an uninitialized N.  An infinite loop may still exist.  Use ret==0 || (ret > 0 && N <= 1)

There are multiple problems:

if scanf() fails to convert the input as a decimal integer, it will return either 0 and the offending input must be discard manually or EOF if end of file or a read error was encountered.  Testing for these conditions explicitly is recommended to ensure proper operation in all cases.
you do not pass the address of N in the main function, so the value read by inserimento() will be lost.
do / while loops are confusing and error prone, I recommend using for ever loops for (;;) and explicit tests.

Here is a modified version:
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int flush_stream(FILE *fp) {
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}

bool inserimento(int *dest) {
    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter a number greater than 1:\n");
        switch (scanf("%d", dest)) {
          case EOF:
            printf("invalid or missing input\n");
            return false;
          case 0:
            flush_stream(stdin);
            printf("invalid input\n");
            break;
          case 1:
            if (*dest > 1)
                return true;
            printf("invalid entry: %d\n", *dest);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int N;
    if (inserimento(&N)) {
        /* do something with N */
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

